# Importing a mysql-dump into an empty PhpMyAdmin database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento, phpmyadmin

Hello stackoverflow community,

I'm fairly new to the whole programma together with databases so i dont know all the ins and outs but im trying to learn.

Currently i received multiple sql-dump's of my companies database. These files contain both tables and data (i dont know if this is obvious or not). **The problem i'm experiencing is that the files are to large to import at once.** I browsed the web and even these forums but there are no specific solutions to my problem. I'm hosting everything locally using **Xampp**. The thing i'm trying to achieve is to link the backup i'm importing to a newly created Magento shell to create a testing environment for us to work in.

**Edit**

So i've changed the values in php.ini (xampp\php\php.ini) from > to

```
post_max_size=2M --> post_max_size=1000M
```

and

```
upload_max_filesize=2M --> upload_max_filesize=1000M
```

Cheers for the help in advance,

Thefellowes

Comment: Exactly how big are these files? I'm assuming they are .sql files right?

Comment: @Styphon the files are about15mb and the max upload size in PhpMyAdmin is 2mb and yes they are .sql files.

Comment: Wich OS are you ussing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using LAMPP or XAMPP, Here is the solution: Open the `php.ini` file at the path of `/opt/lampp/etc` and at the line of 735, you can see as `post_max_size = 20M` and at line no: 886, `upload_max_filesize = 20M`

Here in both the places, enter your desired file size, perferably more than as required. then restart the server that you use may be apache or anything.

**EDIT:**

If you change the above suggested values and if u restart the server, the value near the browse button will change and you given. See the below screenshot for ur reference.

[image]

If you change both the values and restart the server the value displayed here also has to get changed.

Comment: First of all thanks for responding so fast, secondly changing those values does not seem to increase the size at all. I still get the same message stating that the file size is to big to be uploaded.

Comment: thanks again for putting so much effort into this. I get that increasing the size in the code should help but the value in PhpMyAdmin remains the same. Is there a setting that overrules this or something?

Comment: after changing those values are you restarting the server? After restarting the server, Logout from phpmyadmin and Login again..

Comment: Firstly ZIP your files.This will reduce a lot of time and space also. You can directly import zip files in phpmyadmin.

Comment: On a live system where you're doing a reasonable amount of business 20M isn't even enough. Try for 100M and extend the timeouts, or better yet get SSH access and do it from the command line unless you can't handle the speed.

Comment: Do it from command line much easier. `mysql -u root -p your_database_name_here < {your_sql_file.sql}`. You need to create an empty database before you issue the command.

Comment: @PavanKumar no the issue hasen't beem resolved yet. AshleySwatton where should i put the file before issuing that command?

Comment: Nevermind guys i managed to solve it. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: So let us know how u solved it. So that it will be useful to others also